# How to detect browser support cookies only once?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies

I know how to check if client browser support cookies:
`filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Browser.Cookies`

So I put this code in to the `OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)` method.
But I don't want to check client browser every time during user making a request.
Is there any way to detect this information from anywhere in project only once?
Here the full code:

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    HttpContext.Application["AlertOverCookies"] = null;
    if (!filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Browser.Cookies)
    {
        HttpContext.Application["AlertOverCookies"] = "Browser does not support Cookies!";
        filterContext.Result = RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you want to check multiple times?

Comment: @usr This redundancy:)

Comment: Can you post code and specify a concrete problem?

Comment: That code does not show any problem. It looks fine. Where are the redundancies?

Comment: @I don't really need to check browser cookies every request. If browser support cookies by the first time it supports them by the future actions:)

Comment: So you are concerned with performance and nothing else?

Comment: @user3818229 - Your logic is flawed. This code will only run once for *all users and all requests* because you are using the [HttpContext.Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.application(v=vs.110).aspx) object (which returns an instance of [HttpApplicationState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplicationstate(v=vs.110).aspx)). "Enables sharing of global information across multiple sessions and requests within an ASP.NET application."

Comment: @NightOwl888 that's just a bug, that's not his question. Also, the code will still run all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing `filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Browser.Cookies` is extremely cheap. For that reason it is not necessary to reduce the number of calls to it.

> HttpContext.Application

This is a bug. That's a global collection and will be shared between requests and sessions.

Comment: Thanks for a warning about Application context!